# Npm link not linking because of vite

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vite, npm-link

I'm trying to link two applications together. I have two projects. Both projects using Vue(2). One being the main project and the other a componet lib. I succesfully linked the two projects together with npm link. However my main project is giving an error.

**ERROR  Failed to resolve entry for package "@hitfoyb/my-component-library". The package may have incorrect main/module/exports specified in its package.json: Failed to resolve entry for package "@hitfoyb/my-component-library". The package may have incorrect main/module/exports specified in its package.json.**

My main application is using vite and the component application is using webpack.

in my main.js I'm importing it like any other lib

```
import thqComponentLibrary from "@hitfoyb/my-component-library/dist/MycomponentLibrary.umd";
import "@hitfoyb/my-component-library/dist/MycomponentLibrary.css";

 Vue.use(MycomponentLibrary);
```

my main application vite.config.js

```
    optimizeDeps: { 
      include: ['@hitfoyb/my-component-library']
    },
```

Any help on why the application is giving the error and how do I resolve it?